# Is there an optimal strike indicator color for fly fishing reflective, tumbling streams?

Tags: fly-fishing

Strike indicators are basically the fly fishing version of bobbers and they come in different colors white, yellow, orange, etc.

When fishing streams that have a big of disturbance and the sun is reflecting just right it is hard to watch the indicator even with polarized sunglasses.

Would there be an **optimal color to best see the strike indicator?**

Answer (score 1):

Darker colours of indicator like black or dark red work well and white is probably the worst colour high glare situations. An indicator made of light and dark colours can help with visibility in a variety of conditions.

Hot pink seems to be a great colour for standing out in a variety of conditions but it might not be the most subtle colour ...